# JSONata - Deduplicate objects in an array based on a shared value

Tags: arrays, duplicates, jsonata

This is an ecommerce use case where I need to consume all the orders in a day, product a single order header, and list an aggregate summary of line items. This means I need to de-duplicate an array of line item objects based on a shared value (sku). I also need to sum certain fields (quantity, total purchase price) based on that same value.

Example Input:

```
{
  "Account": {
    "Account Name": "Firefly",
    "Order": [
      {
        "OrderID": "order103",
        "Product": [
          {
            "Product Name": "Bowler Hat",
            "ProductID": 858383,
            "SKU": "0406654608",
            "Description": {
              "Colour": "Purple",
              "Width": 300,
              "Height": 200,
              "Depth": 210,
              "Weight": 0.75
            },
            "Price": 50.0,
            "Quantity": 2
          },
          {
            "Product Name": "Trilby hat",
            "ProductID": 858236,
            "SKU": "0406634348",
            "Description": {
              "Colour": "Orange",
              "Width": 300,
              "Height": 200,
              "Depth": 210,
              "Weight": 0.6
            },
            "Price": 21.67,
            "Quantity": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "OrderID": "order104",
        "Product": [
          {
            "Product Name": "Bowler Hat",
            "ProductID": 858383,
            "SKU": "040657863",
            "Description": {
              "Colour": "Purple",
              "Width": 300,
              "Height": 200,
              "Depth": 210,
              "Weight": 0.75
            },
            "Price": 100,
            "Quantity": 4
          },
          {
            "ProductID": 345664,
            "SKU": "0406654603",
            "Product Name": "Cloak",
            "Description": {
              "Colour": "Black",
              "Width": 30,
              "Height": 20,
              "Depth": 210,
              "Weight": 2
            },
            "Price": 107.99,
            "Quantity": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Desired Output:

```
{
  "header": "Some Header Fields...",
  "line items": [
    {
      "Product Name": "Bowler Hat",
      "ProductID": 858383,
      "SKU": "0406654608",
      "Description": {
        "Colour": "Purple",
        "Width": 300,
        "Height": 200,
        "Depth": 210,
        "Weight": 0.75
      },
      "Price": 150,
      "Quantity": 6
    },
    {
      "Product Name": "Trilby hat",
      "ProductID": 858236,
      "SKU": "0406634348",
      "Description": {
        "Colour": "Orange",
        "Width": 300,
        "Height": 200,
        "Depth": 210,
        "Weight": 0.6
      },
      "Price": 21.67,
      "Quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "ProductID": 345664,
      "SKU": "0406654603",
      "Product Name": "Cloak",
      "Description": {
        "Colour": "Black",
        "Width": 30,
        "Height": 20,
        "Depth": 210,
        "Weight": 2
      },
      "Price": 107.99,
      "Quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I know I can get an array of skus using $distinct(), but I can't figure out how to produce wholly distinct objects with their values preserved.

I don't think I can apply merge because some parts (qty) of the object are not unique, and I can't figure out how to merge on just certain fields within the object itself.

Lastly, I'm working in a platform that does not have code snippets, so I can't call on javascript. Is this possible in pure JSONata?

Answer (score 1):

Found grouping documentation. I was able to group by sku using 
$lineItems := Account.Order.Product{
SKU:{
"price": $sum(Price),
"qty":$sum(Quantity),
"sku":$distinct(SKU)}}

This generates a node with each key being the SKU, so I map "output_line_items": $lineItems.* which gives me the entries underneath each sku field.

Note in my example, SKUs do not actually match accross products, ProductID would have been a better example. But SKU was used for my specific use case.